# how to sort a query base on 2 different conditions in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a query in laravel that i want my user to be able to sort it in 2 different ways . one of them is hits which is the model it self field but the other is the field which is in relation of that model :

```
  $data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationFacilities','gallery', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])->when($bed_count, function ($q, $bed_count) {
        $q->with([
            'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($bed_count) {
                $q->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
            }
        ]);
    })
        ->whereIn('city_id', $city_id)
        ->whereIn('grade_stars', $stars)
        ->orWhere('accommodation_type_id', $type_id)
        ->paginate(10);
```

so here above the hits filed is existing in accommodation model the price is in roomPricingHistorySearch i want my api to sort by any of the 2 that user sends to it would be conditional i think if user sends sort_price for example it sortt by price and if user sends sort_hit it sorts by hits for api .

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
 $data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationFacilities','gallery', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])->when($bed_count, function ($q, $bed_count) {
        $q->with([
            'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($bed_count) {
                $q->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
            }
        ]);
    })
        ->whereIn('city_id', $city_id)
        ->whereIn('grade_stars', $stars)
        ->orWhere('accommodation_type_id', $type_id);

if(request()->sort_hit ){ // or == 'blabla'
    $data = $data->orderBy('hit');
}elseif(request()->sort_price){ // == A-Z or Z-A for order asc,desc
    $data = $data->orderBy('price');
}

$data = $data->paginate(10);
```

Comment: the first sort which is by hits is working but the second one which is in relationship dos not working and throwing error and sales price column is not found any idea ?

Comment: is the `price` column at accommodations table? If not you can't use is it simply.

Comment: no its not and i found the problem i cant find the solution i am loading the relationship in resource so idk how to sort my result there :|

Comment: Don't use sub query, use join instead of it. Best way i think.